# Headaer inputs in ionic project nor showing

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using copy paste code from ionic docs for header inputs
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#bar-inputs

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
   <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
  <button class="button button-clear">
    Cancel
  </button>
</div>
```

But I am not seeing it.
I only want my header to be a search bar in one view.

Heres the views code beginning:

```
<ion-view>
  <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear">
       Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
  <ion-content>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **[Header Inputs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#input-icons)** two way

1) Add in **index.html**

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </label>
    <button class="button button-clear">
        Cancel
      </button>
</div>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

2) Add in **index.html**

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

and in your template page(**e.g. template/home.html**)

```
<ion-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
          </label>
        <button class="button button-clear">
            Cancel
          </button>
    </div>
    <ion-content>
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjGE8AN1cqki9PI2PFri?p=preview)**

Comment: The latter one is excatly what I did and it is also in my example code. I am still not seeing the search bar.

Comment: In my index.html I have
'  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
  </body>'

The ion-nav-bar is nesseccary but it breaks the header input. Any way around it?